# Creating a sign-in page for multi-tenant customer portal

Tags: asp.net-core, web-applications, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, multi-tenant

My company wants to create a customer portal for business customers, where customers with a support plan can sign in to access resources related to our products and services. We have internal customers belonging to our own Azure AD tenant, external customers with their own Azure AD tenant, and customers without a Microsoft relation that would require a basic username/e-mail and password sign-in.

Since this is a customer portal, we would like to hide the different sign-in options so that our customers don't see the other customers' domains. One way to realize this is to sign in to a B2C tenant, with different Azure AD identity providers pr. customer tenant, in addition to basic e-mail and password sign-in. However this will list all identity providers, one for company A, one for company B, one for company C and one for e-mail/password. How is it possible to use domain-hint to redirect to the correct identity provider? Is it necessary to use custom policies?

Will it be necessary to have a sign-in page where the customer enters their e-mail address, and is then redirected to the correct identity provider? Will this work with SSO, so that the customer don't have to enter their e-mail in order to sign in if they have signed in before?
Some tips are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin#redirect-sign-in-to-a-social-provider), but it does not show how the correct query parameters can be inserted in the redirect URL from the web app.

I have som previous experience on building web apps with ASP.NET Core and using [Microsoft Identity Web](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web) for authentication, and would prefer to use these technologies for the customer portal.

Comment: We used custom policies to achieve this scenario.

Comment: But you still need a custom page in your web app that collects the e-mail address of the user? How do you redirect to this page when authorization is required? And how do you insert the `login_hint` or `domain_hint` in the authorization request?

Comment: We actually have a first step in the policy that gets the user email, resolves their IdP and handles authentication accordingly after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this sample:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern

“For scenarios where you need to implement a sign in journey, where the user is automatically directed to their federated identity provider based off of their email domain entered at the B2C sign in page.”